# Python dictionaries formatting

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, tabular

Python3 I have a dictionary with alphabet count, shown below

```
a 24873
b 5293
c 7301
d 15567
e 38088
f 6499
g 7109
h 20360
i 20283
j 751
k 3207
l 12780
m 7686
n 21510
o 24944
p 5275
q 191
r 16751
s 18831
t 30897
u 9624
v 2551
w 8390
x 439
y 7139
z 161
```

and i want a function to print it as

```
 e 38088 i 20283 w 8390 b 5293 q 191
 t 30897 s 18831 m 7686 p 5275 z 161
 o 24944 r 16751 c 7301 k 3207
 a 24873 d 15567 y 7139 v 2551
 n 21510 l 12780 g 7109 j 751
 h 20360 u 9624  f 6499 x 439
```

I tried taking keys and values into lists but is randomly changing as a dictionary is not ordered. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict.items()` to get the key-value pairs as a list of tuples. Then sort this list by the value.

For example:

```
d = {
    'a': 24873,
    'b': 5293,
    'c': 7301,
    'd': 15567
}

for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    print("{} {}".format(k, v))

#a 24873
#d 15567
#c 7301
#b 5293
```

We sort the key-value pair tuples using a custom key, `lambda x: x[1]`, which gets the element at index 1 in the tuple. In this case, that element is the count.

Also, we specify `reverse=True` to indicate that we want the sorted list to be in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def printCol(l, numCols=5):
    """Takes a sorted list 'l' and displays it in 'numCols', the first items 
    get into col1, the next in col2 etc."""

    # partition the sorted list
    steps = len(l)//numCols+1
    part = [l[i:i+steps] for i in range(0,len(l),steps)]
    # transpose it into tuple-rows
    zpart = zip_longest(*part,())
    for row in zpart: 
        for t in row: 
            if t:  # zip_longest produces () - do not display them
                print(t[1],t[0], end = " ")
        print("") # newline
```

You have to prepare your data a bit:

```
d ={"a":24873,"b":5293  ,"c":7301  ,"d":15567 ,"e":38088 ,
    "f":6499  ,"g":7109  ,"h":20360 ,"i":20283 ,"j":751   ,
    "k":3207  ,"l":12780 ,"m":7686  ,"n":21510 ,"o":24944 ,
    "p":5275  ,"q":191   ,"r":16751 ,"s":18831 ,"t":30897 ,"u":9624  ,
    "v":2551  ,"w":8390  ,"x":439   ,"y":7139  ,"z":161     }

# list comp: create tuples of (count, character) so sort will sort it by count
l = [ (am,ch) for ch,am in d.items()] # create tuples, amount first for sorting
l.sort(reverse=True) # sort descending by count, if equal, then by char

printCol(l,5) # print it
```

Output:

```
e 38088 i 20283 w 8390 b 5293 q 191
t 30897 s 18831 m 7686 p 5275 z 161
o 24944 r 16751 c 7301 k 3207
a 24873 d 15567 y 7139 v 2551
n 21510 l 12780 g 7109 j 751
h 20360 u 9624 f 6499 x 439
```

Comment: Thankyou. I was basically looking for native loop programming for this but this also works and to format the last row as the number of digits are uneven v can use rjust() method

Answer (score 0):

## This is the solution I figured out with just traditional loops and not many in built functions. ThankYou

```
<pre>
def printTable(value):               
    no_of_rows = len(value)//5+1
    i = 0
    while(i < no_of_rows):
        for j in range(0, len(value), no_of_rows):
            if i+j < len(value):
                print(str(value[i+j][0]).rjust(3),
                      str(value[i+j][1]).rjust(5), end="   ")
        print("")
        i += 1

d ={"a":24873, "b":5293, "c":7301, "d":15567, "e":38088,
    "f":6499, "g":7109, "h":20360, "i":20283, "j":751,
    "k":3207, "l":12780, "m":7686, "n":21510, "o":24944,
    "p":5275, "q":191, "r":16751, "s":18831, "t":30897,
    "u":9624, "v":2551, "w":8390, "x":439, "y":7139,
    "z":161}

dic_to_sortlist = sorted(alph_freq.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1),
                        reverse=True)

printTable(dic_to_sortlist)
</pre>
```